# RabbitMq Pika ConnectionResetError on _AsyncBaseTransport._consume()

Tags: python, rabbitmq, python-pika

Observing below error in flask app using pika for rabbitmq,

using pika version 1.1.0
rabbitmq version 3.8.5

Note: Heartbeat value configured is 900 (Higher value set because of long running operation, so i've to keep the connection alive between pika and rabbitmq)

connection loss happening after a period of time, i've to restart app to connect rabbitmq once again. could someone point me in right direction as to what exactly going wrong!

```
ERROR:pika.adapters.utils.io_services_utils:_AsyncBaseTransport._consume() failed, aborting connection: error=ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None); sock=<socket.socket fd=556, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=6, laddr=('0.0.0.0', 65083), raddr=('0.0.0.0', 5672)>; Caller's stack:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pika\adapters\utils\io_services_utils.py", line 1041, in _on_socket_readable
  File "pika\adapters\utils\io_services_utils.py", line 791, in _consume
  File "pika\adapters\utils\io_services_utils.py", line 79, in retry_sigint_wrap
  File "pika\adapters\utils\io_services_utils.py", line 846, in _sigint_safe_recv
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pika\adapters\utils\io_services_utils.py", line 1041, in _on_socket_readable
  File "pika\adapters\utils\io_services_utils.py", line 791, in _consume
  File "pika\adapters\utils\io_services_utils.py", line 79, in retry_sigint_wrap
  File "pika\adapters\utils\io_services_utils.py", line 846, in _sigint_safe_recv
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
ERROR:pika.adapters.base_connection:connection_lost: StreamLostError: ("Stream connection lost: ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)",)
ERROR:pika.adapters.blocking_connection:Unexpected connection close detected: StreamLostError: ("Stream connection lost: ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)",)
```

Comment: I am having the same issue... did you fix it? Do you have some updates about how you did?